# Cannot add powershell snapin, when executing from MSBuild project

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I have powershell script, that adds snapin.

```
if ((get-pssnapin  | select-string "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell") -eq $null) { 
     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell 
}
```

It works when invoking from powershell command line

However, when I invoke it from build.proj (msbuild project) using:

```
<Exec Command="powershell -executionpolicy Unrestricted -Command &quot;&amp; { . \&quot;$(SourceDir)myscript.ps1\&quot;; }&quot;" 
      LogStandardErrorAsError="true" ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

it says:

**The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.**

```
build.proj(82,5): error : Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerSh
build.proj(82,5): error : ell' is not installed on this computer.
```

Comment: It might be that MSBuild is running in either 32-bit/64-bit and the snap-in is installed for only one of the two. I would try loading the snap-in in both x86 and x64 PowerShell consoles to check.

Comment: When you say it works from the commandline, do you mean locally or on the build agent?  What version of TFS?

Comment: @chief7: I run it on my local PC. VS2015 connencting to TFS2013. On tfs server I have another problem: `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell snapin on the build agent before you can add the snapin to the session.  I believe it is part of the [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f) download.

As Al-Muhandis suggests in the comments make sure it is installed in both 32-bit and 64-bit.